# Kubernetes role for reading pod's logs only

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to specify role for reading pod's logs only. I mean, I would like to be able to perform:

```
kubectl logs <PODNAME>
```

and not:

```
kubectl get pod <PODNAME> -oyaml
```

I have below Role

```
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: log-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods", "pods/log"]
  verbs: ["*"]
```

Which allows me to perform both actions. When I've changed role to:

```
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: log-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/log"]
  verbs: ["*"]
```

Following error appeared:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): pods "<PODNAME>" is forbidden: User "user1" cannot get resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
```

Which lead me to conclusion that I have to add `resources: ["pods"]` which allows me to get pod definition.